# Get array value after click button if adding from php to ajax

Tags: html, jquery, arrays

my code he work like that , he get array information form php file to AJAX

Code HTML is

```
<tbody id="TdFromAjaxGroun">

</tbody>
```

i get `<tr></tr>` information form php id do this in ajax

```
for (i8 = 0; i8 < data.info.length; i8++) { 

  $("#TdFromAjaxGroun").append('<tr> <td><div class="col-lg-3"><span>' + data.info[i8].idvalue + '</span></div></td> <td><div class="col-lg-3"><span>' + data.info[i8].Translation + '</span></div></td> <td><div class="form-group text-right col-lg-9"><select class="form-control" id="groubup1"> <option value="'+data.info[i8].status+'">'+data.info[i8].status+'</option> <option value="SHOW">عرض</option> <option value="HIDE">اخفاء</option> </select></div></td> </tr>');

}
```

you can see i am add `<option></option>` i want after click button get all change users  array

i cant Get to array

if try with this code

```
$('#UpdateNewgroupshowhide').on('click', function () {

    var id = $('#groubup1').val();

    alert(id);

});
```

but i cant see any thinks

Comment: Since the ajax likely works well, next time please  click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] with the object you got from the Ajax and relevant HTML and script.

Comment: Also IDs need to be unique and you did not show if UpdateNewgroupshowhide wa part of the Ajax or already on the page